# When I run fswatch on an additional thread that starts, it cannot be closed by CTRL C. Why is this happening?

Tags: c++, multithreading, select

The fswatch.hpp is in the [fswatch](https://github.com/p-ranav/fswatch)

```
#include "fswatch.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
void go()
{
  auto watcher = fswatch("~", "/opt", ".");

  watcher.on(fswatch::Event::FILE_CREATED, [](auto &event) {
    std::cout << "File created: " << event.path << std::endl;
  });

  watcher.on(fswatch::Event::FILE_MODIFIED, [](auto &event) {
    std::cout << "File modified: " << event.path << std::endl;
  });

  watcher.on(fswatch::Event::FILE_DELETED, [](auto &event) {
    std::cout << "File deleted: " << event.path << std::endl;
  });

  try {
    watcher.start();
  } catch (std::filesystem::filesystem_error &error) {
    std::cout << error.what() << std::endl;
  }
}
int main() {
  std::thread t1(go);
  t1.join();
}
```

Why does it take me a long time to wait for the program to exit when I press ctrl c?

When the code is as follows, you can use ctrl c to immediately exit.

```
int main() {
  go();
}
```

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide a detailed explanation.

Comment: You'll probably want to create a signal handler and call `stop` from it

Comment: Yes, what puzzles me is that a signal handler is defined in fswatch.cpp, which can receive signals in the t1 thread but cannot exit immediately.

Comment: `run` isn't atomic so the code has undefined behaviour.  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27204444/not-able-to-catch-sigint-signal-while-using-select